# How to convert String to One Int

Tags: c#, string, int, visual-studio-community

following problem in C# (working in VS Community 2015):

First off, i fairly new to C#, so excuse me if that question would be an easy fix.

I have a contact sensor giving me a string of numbers (length measurement). I read them with the SystemPort Methods and cut them down to the numbers that i need with substring (as the beginning of the string, the "SR00002" is useless to me).

In the end i end up with a string like : "000.3422" or "012.2345". Now i want to convert that string to one solid int-variable that i can work with, meaning subtract values from and such.

Bsp: I want to calculate 012.234 - 000.3422 (or , instead of . but i could change that beforehand)

I already tried Parse and ConvertToInt (while iterating through the string) but the endresult is always a string.

```
    string b = serialPort2.ReadLine();
    string[] b1 = Regex.Split(b, "SR,00,002,");
    string b2 = b1[1].Substring(1);
    foreach (char c in b2)
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(c);
    }                
    textBox2.Text = b2 + b2.GetType();
```

I know that when b2 will be int it can not be printed in the Textbox but ill take care of that later.

When everything is converted accordingly, ill outsource the conversion to its own method =)

The GetType is just for testing and as said shows only System.String (which i dont want). Help would be much appreaciated. I also browsed the searchfunction and google but couldnt find anything of help. I wish any possible helpers a nice day, mfg Chris.

Comment: If you want to keep the decimal points then you need to convert the `string` to `double`, ``decimal`, or `float` .. have a look at `decimal.Parse` and `decimal.TryParse ` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx (you can also do this for other numeric types)

Comment: b2 is an string, so if yo do b2.GetType you'll get at result string.You are converting the string but you are not declaring anything with the returned integer from ToInt32();.

Comment: thanks you for such quick answers. I tried the decimal.TryParse. It cuts the zeroes at the beginning but in retrospective that could be actually quite good as this way i get the amount of signals the sensor reads and this is basically what i need =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the int.Parse

int.Parse("123")

Comment: worked with:
decimal b3 = decimal.Parse(b1[1]);
Sadly does not register the decimalpoint and displays one big number but still could work with the number this parse method provides as it displays the number of readings the sensor does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the converted values to a new variable or array that takes `int` or other numeric values that you want.

```
int[] numbers = new int[b1.length];
for(int i = 0; i < b2.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i]  = Convert.ToInt32(b2[i]);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Ill definetley try around with that one. But would this way not destroy the decimal number and just give me (in the solution you provided) an array with the numbers instead of a solid float/decimal. I might have expressed myself initially a bit bad, didnt want an int but rather a solid number to do calculations with =)

Comment: @Chrisoph-Poser ah sorry, I see you found your solution. Yes you can just replace the `int` with `double`, `decimal` or `float` depending on your needs but I would go with `float` in that case.